# Google Sheet Split Text To Column automation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet that receives data from a form that I need to have one cell from the submission get split to columns on a specific delimiter. I have used the "Split text to columns" function in the Data menu which works perfectly but I need this to happen every time a new form is submitted.

So, the trigger "on form submit", split the data in cell C into cells C, D, and E using the delimiter " > ".

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a native function using regexreplace and a literal array formula :

```
=arrayformula(if(istext(A1:A),{arrayformula(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A,">.*","")),arrayformula(regexextract(A1:A,"^.*>(.*)>.*$")),arrayformula(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A,"^.*>",""))},))
```

[image]

The reason Arrayformula does work for this is also because I included the `if is text` portion, it will only extend the formula to that row once your data has imported by the form, but it wont block rows from importing since it is only a single formula on the first row

Comment: The arrayformula definitely is the way to go but do note that the empty rows will not evaluate as empty as the cells will have a value of "". So be careful when doing further tests in additional formulas.

Comment: @Karl_S The rows dont have a value of "" because i deliberately ended the statement with , and nothing else instead of ,""

Comment: Nice. I was not aware of that option. Thank you. RE the formula, the following edit allows it to be in Row 1 and use that row as a Header row. You manually add the header for column A, it adds them in columns B-D This limits the possibility it will be over-written by others. I also used a Not IsBlank combo to show a different option on the test: 

`=arrayformula(if(not(isblank(A1:A)),IF(ROW(A1:A) = ROW(A1), {"Parameter 1", "Parameter 2", "Parameter 3"}, {arrayformula(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A,">.*","")),arrayformula(regexextract(A1:A,"^.*>(.*)>.*$")),arrayformula(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A,"^.*>",""))}),))`

Comment: This is close to what I need. However, since I need to keep the data in the original cell (your column A) it'd get a cyclical dependency error. I was thinking it'd have to be a script in order to parse my column C into C, D, and E.

http://i.imgur.com/CHQeKLV.png

A form gets submitted and the path needs to get split when it gets to the sheet. The first three lines in the example show it split and the next two aren't.